# Homomorphism between an abelian group and the complex multiplicative group

Tags: group-theory

I've come across this problem and as I've found it rather interesting I've tried to find another solution beside the most obvious one; I won't write down the problem word for word for pragmatism:

Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism other than the unit from an abelian group G to the multiplicative complex group; show that $\sum_{g\in G} \phi(g) = 0$.

Now the only case we should consider is the one in which $G$ is cyclic. Let $g$ be a generator of order $k$, so that we have $\phi(g^k)$=1 implying $\phi(g)^k=1$; but if we set $\phi(g)=a+bi$, we have $(a+bi)^k=1$, so that $\phi(g)=cos({2\pi/r})+isin({2\pi/r})$ and $\phi(g^j)=cos({2j\pi/r})+isin({2j\pi/r})$.
Thus we just need to evaluate $\sum_{}^r cos({2j\pi/r})$ and $\sum_{}^r sin({2j\pi/r})$. Given that these sums are both null, we should have our result.

My doubt concerns the statement $\phi(g)=cos({2\pi/r})+isin({2\pi/r})$, but I think it is rigorous enough.

Comment: Your group must be finite, no?

Comment: Use, for example, `$\sin x$` for $\sin x$.

Comment: The author does not explicitly said so; maybe it's just my method that can work only is the finite case

Answer (score 1):

For finite groups, the image of $\phi$ will be the $n$th roots of unity $\mu_n$ for some $n$, and
$$
\sum_{g\in G}\phi(g)=|\ker \phi|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{2\pi i k/n}=0
$$
(assuming $n>1$).

[For infinite groups ($\phi(G)$ infinite), your sum won't make sense, e.g. for the cyclic group generated by $z\in\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, the sum
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}z^n
$$
won't converge no matter how the terms are ordered since the terms of the series won't converge to zero.]

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense for infinite groups?

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot.

Comment: $\sum_{g\in G} \phi(g) = | \ker \phi |  \sum_{\omega\in\mu_n} \omega =0$